# Converting JSONL to Array with PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have this piece of code to get the file from AWS S3 using `aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel` package.

```
try {
    $s3Client = AWS::createClient('s3');
    $result = $s3Client->getObject([
        'Bucket'    => static::$s3Bucket,
        'Key'       => $fileName
    ]);

    return $result['Body']->getContents();
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    return;
}
```

it working fine, but when I tried to using `explode(PHP_EOL, $result['Body']->getContents());` it's only showing 1 array, and inside that array there will be the result from the `jsonl` file, so how to extract the `json` data from `jsonl` file?

Comment: please show use the output of `var_export($result['Body']->getContents());`. so that we can come to know how actual data look like and why you are facing issue

Comment: It's possible that the platform uses a different line encoding - try `explode("\n",`

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen, silly me forcing to use the `PHP_EOL` instead `"\n"`, now its working fine

Comment: Hi @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie thanks for your comment, I just put the wrong delimiter right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `PHP_EOL`, you are using the line break for your specific platform.  This may be different than the file encoding.

In the [spec of JSONL](http://jsonlines.org/)...

> 3. Line Separator is '\n'

So if your platform uses `\r\n` for end of lines (`PHP_EOL`) then it won't split the lines.

The solution is to always use `\n` for JSONL files...

```
explode("\n", $result['Body']->getContents());
```